# How do I implement in Prolog the predicate list_for_set

Tags: prolog

How do I implement in Prolog the predicate list_for_set(Xs, Cs) where Cs is a list that contains the same elements as Xs, in the order of its first occurrence, but whose number of occurrences is only 1. For example, the query

```
? - list_for_set([1, a, 3.3, a, 1.4], Cs).
```

it happens only for Cs = [1, a, 3,4]. The consultation

```
? - list_for_set ([1, a, 3,3, a, 1,4], [a, 1,3,4])
```

must fail.

The Cs list of the previous statement will be called a set list, that is, a list with only one occurrence of each element.

Comment: Come on, OP, this isn't so hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is some trickery involved.

```
foofilter([],_,_-T) :- T=[]. % close difflist

foofilter([L|Ls],Seen,H-T) :-
   member(L,Seen),
   !,
   foofilter(Ls,Seen,H-T).

foofilter([L|Ls],Seen,H-T) :-
   \+member(L,Seen),
   !,
   T=[L|NewT],
   foofilter(Ls,[L|Seen],H-NewT).
```

```
:-begin_tests(filter).

data([1, a, 3, 3, a, 1, 4]).

test(one) :- data(L),
             DiffList=[[]|T]-T,  % Assume [] is never in L
             foofilter(L,[],DiffList),
             DiffList=[_|Result]-_,
             format("~q ==> ~q\n",[L,Result]),
             Result = [1,a,3,4].

:-end_tests(filter).

rt :- run_tests(filter).
```

Run tests:

```
?- rt.
% PL-Unit: filter [1,a,3,3,a,1,4] ==> [1,a,3,4]
. done
% test passed
true.
```

Someone will probably come up with a one-liner.

Comment: Can you please remind me of how diff lists work again?

Comment: @Enigmativity Try my explainer: https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/difflists

Comment: @Enigmativity but the dummy element `[]` irks me. It must be possible to do without.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok, it works without the dummy entry, I will have to update my images at the above link.